# Chromedriver with Selenium

Tags: selenium

### I added the chromedriver path and still receive this error when i load chromedriver via selenium.

pry(main)> browser=Watir::Browser.new(:chrome)
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:  Unable to find chromedriver. Please download the server from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and place it somewhere on your PATH. More info at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver.
from /home/roberto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.12.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:57:in `binary_path'

---

so i already have the chromedriver and i can access it via cmd direct but not via selenium using ruby

what i missing here.. can someone highlight it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you download the chromedriver binary from here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/ and paste it into your automated test project directory root. Then when you specify in your code to instantiate your driver you can simply do this:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service.driver_path = File.join(Dir.pwd, 'chromedriver')
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome)
```

Im not familiar with watir driver but this is how I've done it with selenium-webdriver gem in the past

Answer (score 0):

A little more information may be helpful in us trying to help you out. Have you looked into these points in the documentation?

- The chromedriver binary is in the system path, or
- The Selenium Server was started with -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=c:\path\to\your\chromedriver.exe

Comment: obviously i need to the chromedriver to the path using bash on windows for the app using rails.... 
So i added all the gem, and i think i am not adding the path correctly.. 
the path already exist on the environment but for some reason selenium driver (gem ) is not reading the chromedriver path..

Comment: I'm not super familiar with ruby but is there some configuration that needs to be done on your gem?